# Can we embed another JavaScript in Cordova function(PhoneGap)?

Tags: javascript, cordova

can we call or put any other java script code like jquery mobile in a function of cordova phonegap?
like i have one function below

```
 function onOffline() {
    //here i want to put another javascript
 }
```

is it possible show me various ways.

Comment: phonegap generates set of events which you can register to call your functions http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `onOffline` is a callback from the listener on the offline event (such as the one in the docs):

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    // Handle the offline event
}
```

Then you can put whatever js you like in that callback including using frameworks such as jQuery or zepto etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create native application then you never change the cordova.js file,but for the specific platform you can.